# find stored procedures which uses user defined functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a user defined functions name
GET_SPQ_FUNCION

which is used in many stored procedures .Now I need to remove the Input parameter from the function.It will affect many SP's.
Is there any way i can list those SP's using a sql query.

Comment: Well if you use sql developer (and probably in other tools), you can search in source code. Wouldn't this be enough ?

Comment: @Polppan: Yes I use Toad. I need to search in every code. I am just curious if I can list in SQL. If not I have to search individually

Comment: @Mani Well if you use TOAD, in schema browser for each table or function or procedure there is tab in right side called UsedBy which will give information of all the other objects which are being used.

Upon double click on any of the object will open as popup window. This is quite useful in finding out what are the other objects being used by.

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of stored procedures which use your specific function(`GET_SPQ_FUNCION()` in this case), your can query(depending on the privileges granted) [`all`][`dba`][`user`]`_dependencies` view. For instance if the function `GET_SPQ_FUNCION()` is used by, lets say, `GET_SPQ_FUNCION1()` function, then issuing a similar query  against one of the mentioned above views you will get the following output:

```
SQL> select name as usedby
  2       , type
  3       , referenced_name
  4       , dependency_type
  5    from dba_dependencies
  6    where referenced_name = 'GET_SPQ_FUNCION'
  7  ;

Usedby            Type      Referenced Name   Dependency Type 
-------------------------------------------------------------
GET_SPQ_FUNCION1  FUNCTION  GET_SPQ_FUNCION   HARD
```